# React Native - The development server returned response error code 500 (newbie)

Tags: react-native, navigation

After installing reactnavigation the following error occurred to me ...

[image: page1]

[image: page2]

[image: page3]

Comment: have you restarted the server? My experience is that if you have the server running, then install a new package, the server needs to be restarted.

Comment: Yes, I restarted the server.